# send() function is not working

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, hex, send

I am doing a socket program to communicate with a video server control by sending hexadecimal messages. I tried a lot of times figure out what is happening, but I didn't find the error yet.

Here is my completed code:

```
void UsingWinSock()
{
    u_short port;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
    int lenAddrs;
    CString remoteAddress;

    b1 = 192;
    b2 = 168;
    b3 = 11;
    b4 = 2;

    remoteAddress.Format("%u.%u.%u.%u", b1, b2, b3, b4);

    port = (u_short)(portNumber);

    // remote address
    memset(&remote_addr, 0, sizeof(remote_addr));
    remote_addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, remoteAddress, (&remote_addr.sin_addr)); 

    // socket 
    sckSloMo = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sckSloMo == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("sckSloMo is invalid!!");
        return;
    }

    if (sckSloMo != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        ret = connect(sckSloMo, (const sockaddr*) &remote_addr, sizeof(remote_addr));

        if (ret != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            m_status = "Connected!!";
            SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_STATUS, m_status);
        }
        else
        {
            m_status = "connect error!!!";
            SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATIC_STATUS, m_status);
            OnBnClickedButtonCancel();
        }
    }
    else if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("socket not Ok");
        return;
    }

}

void StartSendingMessages()
{
    int retorno;
    const int bufLen = 7;
    CString TextRetorno;
    CString messageSend;

    HEX_bufferMessage = new CHAR[bufLen]; // alocando espaço

    // specifies the led state
    HEX_bufferMessage[0] = 0xF0;
    HEX_bufferMessage[1] = 0x15;
    HEX_bufferMessage[2] = 0x31;
    HEX_bufferMessage[3] = 0x04;
    HEX_bufferMessage[4] = 0x02; // green
    HEX_bufferMessage[5] = 0x0E; // C1
    HEX_bufferMessage[6] = 0xF7;

    retorno = send(sckSloMo, HEX_bufferMessage, bufLen, 0); 

    if (retorno == SOCKET_ERROR || retorno < 0 || retorno == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Error Send!!");
        return;
    }
    else if(retorno != 0)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Send() OK !!");
    }
}
```

No error is raised, but the video server controller doesn't do anything.
Anyone has any idea about what is happening with my program?

Comment: what do you see on wireshark?

Comment: Aside: Why are you allocating memory for HEX_bufferMessage instead of using a static array? (`char HEX_bufferMessage[bufLen];`) Your function doesn't free it and neither does send.

Comment: *Hexadecimal* is not a data type. It's a way of encoding numeric values for display and use as integer literals. `0x10`, `16` and `020` all represent the same value whose binary representation is `10000`.

Comment: Please don't capitalize C++ identifiers, even as the first word of a sentence or title. It's `send()`, not `Send()`. (I've fixed it.)

Comment: `static const HEX_bufferMessage[] = { 0xF0, 0x15, 0x31, 0x04, 0x02, 0x0E, 0xF7 }; send(sckSloMo, HEX_bufferMessage, sizeof(HEX_bufferMessage), 0);` (and remove bufLen entirely) [this is not a fix, just to help you simplify the code]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set socket option 'TCP_NODELAY'. Your message is too small and probably gets delayed for a while.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try this.

Comment: the compiler says that TCP_NODELAY is undeclared identifier. =[

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738596(v=vs.85).aspx) says it's well-defined.